# Why am I getting an error from this square root statement?

Tags: python, math, sqrt

Why am I getting an error from this line?

```
noise=math.sqrt(v1(n1-1) + v2(n2-1))*math.sqrt(1/n1 + 1/n2)
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling your variables v1 and v2, i would look into if these are callable objects or floats.

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
noise=math.sqrt(v1*(n1-1) + v2*(n2-1))*math.sqrt(1/n1 + 1/n2)
#      Missing ---^        ---^
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as soon I checked it again.